# Add Flyway to a project already in production

Tags: java, spring, flyway

I am working on a JAVA project without the Flyway library, the application uses a PosgreSQL database.
The creation of the database, the tables, the indexes... were done via SQL direcement scripts executed on the database server.

I now want to use Flyway for future database modifications but I don't know if it is possible to integrate it on the fly? Can you confirm that this is possible? And if so, is there any particular configuration that needs to be set up?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Flyway - at its core - executes `.sql`-files. If we write the initial `.sql`-file (capturing the current state of the database) defensively (i.e. use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...`), then this should be possible. The first migration should thus capture the current state of the database. We want to capture the whole state of the database, including triggers, materialized views, functions, .... If the "base" is done, we will only modify the database schema through new migration files.

Comment: See the FlywayDB.org page, [*Existing Database Setup*](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/learnmore/existing).

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely can. The core concept would be to ensure that you establish a baseline starting point for all future development. You can do this one of two ways. You can use the concept of [Baseline Migrations](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/baselinemigrations) to set up your existing scripts. Alternatively, you just ignore the existing structures (sort of) and establish where you are the [beginning baseline](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/command/baseline). Then you create migrations from that point forward. Either way will work. It's down to you to decide which will work best in your situation.